# raise ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model

Tags: python, django

raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'book.CustomUser' that has not been installed

`raise ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'book.CustomUser' that has not been installed`

Comment: You shouldn't just post the error message. At least, post the code that throws it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `book` model needs to be installed, so put in the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std-setting-INSTALLED_APPS):

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'book'
]
```